# Thermal Limiter keeps blowing

Tags: dryer

I have a Kenmore laundry center model 41798702891. It would not start and after some checking I found that the thermal limiter fuse was blown. I replaced it and tryed another load only to have it blow within a few min. I have since replaced the dryer operating thermostat, dryer high limit thermostat and dryer timer. It still is blowing the thermal limiter fuse.... I don't know what else to do! Have checked the vent (only 16" long) and fan.
Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Sometimes you just have to cut your losses and replace the appliance...

Comment: There's not much to go wrong in a dryer. I would go back and check those things you think are okay. Specifically for obstructions in the air path and double check the limiter temperature rating. I had something like that happen because my son repeatedly threw baseball pants into the dryer with seeds in the pockets and they obstructed the air path (vent was okay). Animals can do it too.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany good on you for having him do his own laundry! Next step is doing it right. :)

Comment: I have seen the same with sand the air flow was limited and that caused the high heat and thus popped the thermal fuse. There could be some thing like the fan key way had fallen out so there is not enough air flow. Dryers are easy for the most part. You need to look for the cause.